# Permission to read the directory contents is required for each directory up the hierarchy - GitHub runner

Tags: github, github-actions

when I run `command./config.sh` --- while trying to setup GitHub runner on server I get this error

```
An error occurred: Permission to read the directory contents is required for '/var/www/usr/data/actions-runner' and each directory up the hierarchy. Access to the path '/var/www' is denied.
```

```
folder /var/www/ is owned by root, and usr running /.configure command has proper rights on /usr/data/action-runner
```

I tried running above command after adding `"usr"` to sudo then it tells me command must not run as sudo. So there is no winning here. I personally do not want to run command as sudo so I didn't try to figure out this error.

But, burning question I have is why does this configure script cares if it has read permission on `/var/www/`

This kind of does not addup

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sudo chmod  0755 /var/www`, which fixed the problem for me